# Linear Layout margin added by default. How to avoid that? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have created 4 buttons in linear layout. This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

But above layout adding margins all sides for all 3 buttons. Why is that margins is added by default? How to avoid that?

Comment: What do you mean? There is no padding defined in the XML you posted here

Comment: @cricket_007. Exactly i have not defined any padding here. But buttons have a small gap between each other also from both sides of the screens. I just want buttons to  be touched with each other and and with sides

Comment: This may sound silly but add background to each button, as `android:background="#8c9eff"` i tried,it will remove shadow of button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Try this,it works like you want,

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Account"
        android:background="#80ffdd10"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#800aad10"
        android:text="History"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:background="#8c9eff"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the shadow by default of Android Button Widget. However If you want to attach one button with another forcefully then add the following properties to each `buttons` as per needed

```
android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
```

**Note : Increase or decrease the value (*Currently -5dp*) of the properties as it suits.**

Answer (score 0):

In button, set `android:layout_width="0dp"` rather than `wrap_content`

It's because you have given `weight` attribute to buttons in horizontal `LinearLayout`, each `Button` will fill 1/3 of the root layout horizontally.
And if you are using a vertical `Linear Layout`, you should set `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom background, it will solve your problem

```
android:background="#8c9eff"
```